# Plotting average number of steps for Euclid's extended algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I was given the following assignment by my Algorithms professor:

Write a Python program that implements [Euclid’s extended algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). Then perform the following experiment: run it on a random selection of inputs of a given size, for sizes bounded by some parameter N; compute the average number of steps of the algorithm for each input size n ≤ N, and use gnuplot to plot the result. What does f(n) which is the “average number of steps” of Euclid’s extended algorithm on input size n look like? Note that size is not the same as value; inputs of size n are inputs with a binary representation of n bits.

The programming of the algorithm was the easy part but I just want to make sure that I understand where to go from here. I can fix N to be some arbitrary value. I generate a set of random values of a and b to feed into the algorithm whose length in binary (n) are bounded above by N. While the algorithm is running, I have a counter that is keeping track of the number of steps (ignoring trivial linear operations) taken for that particular a and b.

At the end of this, I sum the lengths of each individual inputs a and b binary representation and that represents a single x value on the graph. My single y value would be the counter variable for that particular a and b. Is this a correct way to think about it?

As a follow up question, I also know that the best case for this algorithm is θ(1) and worst case is O(log(n)) so my "average" graph should lie between those two. How would I manually calculate average running time to verify that my end graph is correct?

Thanks.